# Ideal way to load components in sequential order in React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a question regarding component loading in React.js.

Is there a way to load components in a specific order. For instance I have the components for each page of my single page website.
I would like `<homepage />` and it's images to load first than `<profile />`, then `<works />`, and so on...
The idea being that when a user first visit my site, homepage will load instantly(or really quickly) and the rest can follow so at least the user has something to look at before they potentially start scrolling.

I've tried to google "loading components in order with react.js" but no luck.

```
class MainContent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component mounted");
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="main-content">

        <ul className="block">
          <HomePage />
          <ProfilePage />
          <WorksPage />
          <ContactPage />
          <BlogPage />
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My first idea would be to have a promise in `<componentDidMount />` function which would switch a boolean state to true when `<Homepage />` is loaded.

```
<Homepage />

{
  this.state.loaded ? 
    <ProfilePage />
    <WorksPage />
    <ContactPage />
    <BlogPage />
  :
    null
  ;
}
```

Am I on the right track with that train of thought?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Moe

Comment: Do you use `react-router`?

Comment: @GProst I do. why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing just fine. It is a [recommended](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) approach:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
> mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. **If you**
> **need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to**
> **instantiate the network request**. Setting state in this method will
> trigger a re-rendering.

So initially in `render` method render only portions on UI that are immediately available. then in componentDidMount - fire and wait for completion of your promise to fetch the rest of the data, and afterwards call setState to refresh UI to show in full.